# Append information to failed tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have some details I have to print out for a failed test. Right now I'm just outputting this information to STDOUT and I use the -s to see this information. But I would like to append this information to the test case details when it failed, and not need to use the -s option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pytest_runtest_logreport(report)](http://pytest.org/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html#pytest_runtest_logreport) hook:

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
     report.longrepr = "Some message"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep printing to stdout and simply not use `-s`.  If you do this py.test will put the details you printed next to the assertion failure message when the test fails, in a "captured stdout" section.

When using `-s` things get worse since they are also printed to stdout even if the test passes and it also displays during the test run instead of nicely in a section of a failure report.

Comment: Not what I was looking for. I want it in the summary. If I run in a non verbose mode the output will get ugly just printing it out. The answer by Misha looks promising.

Comment: I don't think I understand.  The output won't get ugly without `-s`, whether `-v` is used or not.  To modify the summary (what gets printed during the run rather then after) is much messier as you only have a single character to convey  the test output.

Comment: In my case, the output is created after the run, as I am taking a screenshot of the phantomjs browser if the test is failing, and the location of the screenshot should be added to the summary. My solution in the end was to create a custom pytest_runtest_makereport hook that calls the _pytest.runner default implementation, and the information to the original report longrepr.reprtraceback.extraline. There might be some other way to do this, but this felt like the easiest way.